# How can I find out, whether the model has changed

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

How can I find out, whether the model has changed?
I would like start an command, after creating a new database

I use the initializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<XDataContext>());
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your model change, your database will be dropped and recreated, and that's exactly DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges means.

Comment: Thats clear, but when exactly can I determine, whether the model has changed?

Comment: Your question is not clear for me, your model change when you add/delete/update a field or attribute to your model class

Comment: yes and this state I would like  (automatically) determine. That what DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges internal does. (sorry that a little bit complicated to explain.)

Comment: what do you want to do, if you just want to execute some sql statement after database is recreated, there is a seed function you can call to seed data.

Comment: That's it. The Keyword Seed was what I'm sought. I've overriden now the Seed Method. Thanks!